# Running module in PyCharm vs interactive shell

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem running my module in interactive shell with :

```
python modulea.py
```

I get an import error and some other errors, which I do not see when I run the module in PyCharm. The modulea.py sits in its own package and references another module which also sits in its own package. The structure is like this:

```
package_a:
--modulea.py
--__init__.py
package_b:
--moduleb.py
--__init__.py
resources:
--input.txt
--output.txt
```

in my modulea.py I import moduleb like this:

```
from package_b import moduleb as b
```

and it works like a charm in PyCharm, but gives me ImportError when run from command line. How can I solve this without changing my project structure? I'm also opening txt files giving path like this:

```
with open("../resources/input.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
```

which again gives me error in interactive shell, but works just fine in PyCharm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about IDEs is that they do a lot of the "clerical" work for us behind the scenes and that makes life convenient and productivity skyrocket.  Then it comes time to deploy this as standalone and it doesn't work just a nice.

In this case, PyCharm adds the following for you:

[image]

If you want the same functionality, you will need to mimic what PyCharm is doing and that is to add your content/source roots to your $PYTHONPATH (or %PYTHONPATH% if on Windows) and it will work as expected.  Hope this helps.